# Netty: What to do with unfulfilled Promise in ChannelOutboundHandler write

Tags: java, promise, netty, future

I have been developing a unit test for a Netty `ChannelDuplexHandler` that during  an outbound `write` under certain circumstances will pass a message back inbound again using `fireChannelRead`. For instance:

```
class MyHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {

        // Do stuff

        if (certainCircumstances) {

            ctx.fireChannelRead(inboundStuff);
        }

        if (otherSituation) {

            ctx.writeAndFlush(outboundStuff, promise);

        }
```

So where `otherSituation` is true there's no problem as the `ChannelPromise` is passed on and fulfilled somewhere, but where it isn't then I have a problem.

The `EmbeddedChannel` that I am using for unit-testing this actually checks all the promises that were passed to `write` and throws an `AssertionError` where any of their `isDone()` don't evaluate true.

It seems to me that  because I call `fireChannelRead` instead of `writeAndFlush` (which presumably goes off and marks the promise as *done* elsewhere).

I think that `EmbeddedChannel` is forcing me to confront what may be a latent defect in extant code: I've had a look around and I can't find a specification of how to handle promises in my own application code. Would the following fix be appropriate at the end of my code:

```
if (!otherSituation) promise.setSuccess();
```

Thereby indicating to `EmbeddedChannel` that everything completed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. At the tail of my handler chain I initiate the write like this:

```
        outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        }
```

So clearly I am dependent on on somebody, somewhere calling `setSuccess` or the channel will be closed.

In my case where I am explicitly calling `setSuccess` I am indicating that I am "done" with the chain of `write` operations.

I am presuming that the messages I'm sending back inbound on the channel (through `fireChannelRead`) have done so in a new Thread or "Executor" so the previous `ChannelPromise` does not apply to them.

That being the case: What happens if a failure happens in subsequent `readChannel` operations? The "transaction" has itself been marked as complete though the business logic continues, and a new transaction has commenced ignobly. Perhaps subject for a follow-up question ...